# Finding delays when interacting with sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, windows-server, windows-server-2019

Lately, I've noticed delays in our sql server database when using the `SQL Server management Studio` GUI, when executing simple queries, and with web apps that interact with the DB.

For example, we have an asp.net application that uses this database. The web app and the sql server database are located in the same server. Lately, I've been seeing several *The Wait operation timed out* with different webforms in the page, and I know that the stored procedures invoked are not time-consuming. I don't want to increase the timeouts because I know it's not the stored procedures.

Another example: I use `SQL Server management Studio`. If I want to expand the `Tables` node, it takes an unusually long time to display all the tables. A few times I've gotten time out issues here.

Is there a way to see what the delays are? We have sufficient memory in the server and I've restarted the sql server installation and the server.

Our installation: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU17) (KB5001092) - 13.0.5888.11 (X64)   Mar 19 2021 19:41:38   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: )

Comment: Would be worth using [WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) to monitor for any blocked processes waits

Comment: Turn on the Query Store: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store

Comment: Out-of-date statistics (even sometimes system tables statistics) can be a reason of performance degradation.